# Cakephp Plugin errors on live site, but not localhost site

Tags: php, cakephp

I have two cakephp sites setup for the same site. One is my local version which I develop on, one is the live one.

I installed a User management plugin on both apps, and it works on my localhost site, but not on the live site.

I get this error on the live site:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function usermgmtinit() in /home2/collehn6/public_html/devcr12/app/Plugin/Usermgmt/Controller/Component/UserAuthComponent.php on line 53
```

The line in question is:

```
UsermgmtInIt($this);
```

I tried changing this line to:

```
$this->UsermgmtInIt();
```

And that just game me another error. Why is it working on my local site, but not on the live site?

Answer (score 0):

[The plugin you're referring to](https://github.com/chetanvarshney/User-Management-Plugin-for-Cakephp-2.x) expects you to load [its bootstrap file](https://github.com/chetanvarshney/User-Management-Plugin-for-Cakephp-2.x/blob/master/Config/bootstrap.php#L20) which contains:

```
function UsermgmtInIt(&$controller) {
    ...
```

As such the problem is probably that in your application you're loading the plugin like so:

```
CakePlugin::load('Usermgmt');
```

Wheras it needs to be loaded like so:

```
CakePlugin::load('Usermgmt', array('bootstrap' => true));
```

Check the [Readme](https://github.com/chetanvarshney/User-Management-Plugin-for-Cakephp-2.x) if that doesn't immediately solve the problem.

*It should be no surprise that changing code to be fundamentally different doesn't make it work.*

Comment: That's it.. I have that line in my original code, and yesterday checked if the live version had it, and it seemed like it did. But apparently I was looking at something different... Thanks man!